# Essential use of case analysis with theorem which is independent of ZFC

Tags: logic, proof-theory

The continuum hypothesis ($CH$) is known to be independent of ZFC.

Is it possible that some mathematical theorem $P$ has a proof of the form:

```
Assume CH:
   Argue P
Assume ~CH:
   Argue P
```

Can all such proofs be "automatically" converted into proofs of P which are unconditional, or is it possible that the only proof of a theorem P might be through such a case anaylsis?

Comment: It's hard to answer this, since it involves some nontrivial open problems in proof theory. Namely, what does it mean for two proofs to be the same?

Comment: (Having said that, I do believe that there are some proofs where the argument is somehow nontrivially different. Nothing comes to mind at the moment, though.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila In this case, one might imagine proving that P is true via this disjunctive elimination argument with classical logic, but then prove P is independent if one uses intuitionistic logic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I suppose the theorem "CH or ~CH" trivially satisfies my criteria...

Comment: Well, that's easy. $\{x\in n\mid n=1\land{\sf CH}\lor n=2\land\sf\lnot CH\}$ is not provably inhibited, since $0$ is an element if and only if CH is either true or false.